# post in jquery do not update element

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

EDIT WITH NEW JAVASCRIPT

I am trying to make a "I like this" kinda function but I have a small problem.

I am using this small javascript

```
function coolIt(designid) {
   $.post('cool.php', {designid:designid}, function(data) {
      //alert(data);
      $('#cool_'+designid).text(data);
   });
}
```

And this HTML where the "Like" button is

```
<span class="like"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="coolIt(\''. $row["id"] .'\');"></a><span id="cool_'.$row["id"].'">('. $row["cools"] .')</span></span>
```

The cool.php runs through this:

```
 function UpdateCool($design_id) {
    $fields_up = array("cools" => 'cools + 1');
    $fields_down = array("cools" => 'cools - 1');

    $sql = SQLHandling::updateSQL('tdic_designs', 'id = '. $design_id .'', $fields_up);            

    SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);
}
```

and that works perfectly. It updates the cools field with one increasing value.

When I run `alert(data)` on the javascript it returns nothing and the #cool_1 span element disappears.

Any idea what I might do wrong?

HTML OUTPUT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function coolIt(designid) {
    $.post('cool.php', {designid:designid}, function(data) {
       alert(data);
       $('#cool_'+designid).text(data);
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="allContainer">
    <div id="topArea">
        <div id="topNaviArea">
            <ul id="navi">
                <li class="home"><a href="/testen/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="categories"><a href="categories.php" title="Browse categories">Categories</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li class="faq"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="submit"><a href="submit.php" title="Submit a website">Submit</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php" title="Submit a website">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentBox">
    <div id="login"><a href="#">Login</a> // <a href="#">Register</a></div>             <div id="mainContent">
                    <h1>// <a href="/testen/">Home</a> // <a href="categories.php">Categories</a> // HTML / CSS</h1>            

                 <div id="catMenu">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=5" title="View all designs in 3D">3D</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=3" title="View all designs in Graphic">Graphic</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=1" title="View all designs in HTML / CSS">HTML / CSS</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=4" title="View all designs in Paintings">Paintings</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=2" title="View all designs in Photography">Photography</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=6" title="View all designs in Portals">Portals</a></li><li><a href="categories.php?cat_id=7" title="View all designs in Webshops">Webshops</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <h2>1 designs<br />in this category</h2>
                </div>

                <div id="rightContentBox">                          
                    <ul id="displays">
                        <li class="displayWindow"><div class="dpwImage"><figure><a href="#"><img src="/testen/designs/thatdesigniscool.jpg" width="280" height="175" alt="That Design Is Cool" target="_blank"></a></figure></div><div class="dpwBox"><div class="dpwLeft"><span class="title"><a href="designinfo.php?designid=1">That Design Is Cool</a></span><span class="comments"><a href="designinfo.php?designid=1">Comments (1)</a></span></div><div class="dpwRight"><span class="like"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="coolIt('1');"></a><span id="cool_1">(29)</span></span></div></div> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont really know much php, but it seems to me that you are returning an empty response. The field is disappearing because you are most likley not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved by editing cool.php to the following:

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

define("INCLUDE_DIR", "includes/classes");

/* Autoload classes when used */
function __autoload($class_name) { include(INCLUDE_DIR.'/class.'. strtolower($class_name) . '.php'); } 

SQLHandling::SQLconnect();

if($_POST["designid"] != '') {
    $alreadyExist = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT id FROM tdic_voted WHERE designid="'.(int)$_POST['designid'].'" AND ip="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"'));

    if($alreadyExist == 0) {

     mysql_query(' UPDATE tdic_designs SET cools = cools+1 WHERE id="'.(int)$_POST['designid'].'"');
     $num = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(' SELECT cools FROM tdic_designs WHERE id="'.(int)$_POST['designid'].'" LIMIT 1'));
     echo $num[0];
     mysql_query(' INSERT INTO tdic_voted (designid, ip) VALUES ("'.(int)$_POST['designid'].'","'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'")');

     } else{
        echo 'You already think this is a cool design!';
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are replacing the whole contents of div with just the server response. Why don't you append?

```
$('.likeIt').livequery("click",function(e){
    var designid =  $(this).attr('id').replace('design_id-','');
    $.post('cool.php?design_id='+designid, {}, function(response){
        $('#cool_'+designid).html($('#cool_'+designid).html() + response); // See if this works!
    });
});
```

See if this helps! :)

Comment: With that nothing disappears, but it does not update the span element unlesss I refresh the browser.

Comment: @Morten you need to post the full source code, the server output before we could say anything. :(

Comment: As Josh said, the `cool.php` doesn't return anything! Not even a script to be executed. And in the `onsuccess` function, you are replacing the HTML Contents of that `div` with <nothing>, which makes that count to disappear. :(

Comment: Could you help me in the right direction of what I need to look at?
As I understand it, cool.php does not return anything back to the javascript function?

Comment: If the `cool.php` returns the current like count, it will do good. :)

Comment: @Morten Hagh Praveen is correct. You want cool.php to return the current count. You could manually increment the value yourself, but if there is an error in incrementing in the db the result to the user would be inaccurate.